# Symfony upgrade give me error from 4.1 to 4.4

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I just made the migration from symfony 4.1 to 4.4
I have this error:

> Argument 1 passed to App\EventListener\KernelRequestListener::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage, instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\UsageTrackingTokenStorage given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\chat-project-symfony\var\cache\dev\Container06Mjwya\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php on line 1130

While if you look at my `KernelRequestListener` :

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
//..

class KernelRequestListener
{
    private $tokenStorage;

    /**
     * KernelRequestListener constructor.
     * @param TokenStorage $tokenStorage
     * ...
     */
    public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage/*...*/)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        //..
    }
}
```

Here is my `config/services.yaml` file:

```
#...
services:
  #..
  App\EventListener\KernelRequestListener:
    arguments: [ '@security.token_storage' ]
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request }
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response }
```

I don't know why symfony tell me that I'm using `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\UsageTrackingTokenStorage` while it's clearing written `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage`

I already tried to clear the cache folder and also delete the cache folder and it didn't change.

How can I fix this ?

Thank you

Comment: I think you should be using `TokenStorageInterface`, which is what [`UsageTrackingTokenStorage` implements](https://github.com/symfony/security-core/blob/master/Authentication/Token/Storage/UsageTrackingTokenStorage.php).

Comment: Use `bin/console debug:autowiring | grep TokenStorage` you will see `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface (security.token_storage)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I don't know why symfony tell me that I'm using `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\UsageTrackingTokenStorage` while it's clearing written `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage`

It's not `symfony` but `PHP`'s type checking feature. You are stating that your Listener wants a `TokenStorage` but `symfony` is passing to it different class, thus the error.

So, as @JaredFarrish pointed, you should be using `TokenStorageInterface` in your constructor, like this:

```php
namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
//..

class KernelRequestListener
{
    private $tokenStorage;

    /**
     * KernelRequestListener constructor.
     * @param TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage
     * ...
     */
    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage/*...*/)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        //..
    }
}
```

It's a common practice to use interfaces where they exists, because this way you will loose coupling with other classes and provide a way to unit test your classes.

Take a look: https://github.com/symfony/security-bundle/blob/master/Resources/config/security.xml#L22 they switched class for `@security.token_storage` service, because of deprecation. But when you use an interface you don't care of anything underlying, you just know that you will have your methods because of interface contract.

Comment: be aware there also is Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenStorage\TokenStorageInterface - easy mistake to make when selecting a class in IDE

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it changing this line:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
```

With this one:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface as TokenStorage;
```